# Is this property true?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on the compact set $[0,1]$. Is true that given $\epsilon>0$, there exist $\delta>0$ such that for any partition $P=\{x=x_0<x_1,...,<x_{i-1}<y=x_i\}$ of the interval $[x,y]$, with $|x-y|<\delta$, we have that $$\sum_{n=1}^i|f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})|<\epsilon$$

Comment: Interesting, I don't knew this property, I was trying to prove it only by using the uniformly continuity of $f$.

Comment: What you described is related to bounded variation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#BV_functions_of_one_variable

Comment: In fact, I was trying to prove that if $f$ is continuous, then $V_0^x f$ is continuous. I realized that if $f$ satisfies this property, then  it is easy to show the continuity of $V_0^x f$, but now I saw that my argument is wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in general.  Every continuous function that is not of bounded variation provides a counterexample.

If $f$ is not of [bounded variation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBounded_variation&ei=IqAnUbmEB4Se2gWdq4CIBA&usg=AFQjCNHtBZZg0oYUuss_q6vT8S-Ysymbfw&sig2=4VI-10QEVen9F74yQoa26Q&bvm=bv.42768644,d.b2I), then for all $\delta>0$, there exists an interval $[x,y]\subset [0,1]$ with $|x-y|<\delta$ and there exists a partition $P=\{x=x_0<x_1,...,<x_{i-1}<y=x_i\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^i|f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})|>1$.  This can be seen by breaking up $[0,1]$ into finitely many intervals of length less than $\delta$, because $f$ cannot have bounded variation on all of these without having bounded variation on the entire interval.

This property is implied by absolute continuity, but not conversely.  E.g., every monotone continuous function satisfies this property, but need not be absolutely continuous (for example, the Cantor-Lebesgue function).

Answer (score 5):

Consider the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x=0\\
x\sin\frac1x,&\text{if }0<x\le 1\;;
\end{cases}$$

clearly $f$ is continuous, but you can make

$$\sum_{n=1}^i|f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})|$$

as large as you like when $x=0$, even if $y$ is very small: if you choose the right partition, you’re essentially adding up terms of the harmonic series.

Answer (score 1):

No, the function $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$, $f(0)=0$ is not [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity)

Comment: I think that argument that $xsin(1/x)$ is not absolutely continuous is not right. Becouse cantor function, which is not absolutely continuous, satisfy desired propertie(because it is continuous and monotone).

Answer (score 1):

But function $x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ does not have bounded variation and it is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Sorry, but I really tried to improve the title, but nothing come to my mind.

Comment: "Nondescriptive title" belongs in a comment, not an answer.